# pass mat from dll c++ to imagesource c#

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I'm working with Visual C# 2010, and I like to send an image from DLL C++ to my Visual C# 2010. The image has 166*166*24 to send the image from DLL C++ to C#. I'm using this code:

**main.cpp**

```
unsigned char*   test()
        {
read image from filename
        Mat OriginalImg = imread(fileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); 
         return (OriginalImg.data);} 
  OriginalImg.data return the pointer to the image.
```

**main.h**

```
 extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) unsigned char* test();}
```

and in my program Visual C#, I use this code:

```
 [DllImport("testng.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
               private static extern IntPtr test();

        IntPtr intPtr1;

                    BitmapImage bitmapImage;
        calling the c++ dll
                    intPtr1 = test(1);

                    if (intPtr1.ToString().CompareTo("0") != 0)         
                    {     
create a bitmap with the pointer         
                    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(166, 166, 3 * 166, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, intPtr1);
to show the bitmap i need to convert it to a bitmap image
                    bitmapImage=convertBitmapToBitmapImage(bitmap); 
                    System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush ib = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush();
                    ib.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
i put the image received from c++ dll like a background to my canvas: canvasImage
                    windows.canvasImage.Background = ib;
                    }

         BitmapImage convertBitmapToBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
                {

                   IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

                   BitmapSource retval;

                     try
                        {
                             retval = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                             hBitmap,
                             IntPtr.Zero,
                             Int32Rect.Empty,
                             BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
                        }
                    finally
                       {
                           //DeleteObject(hBitmap);

                        }

                     return (BitmapImage)retval;



                }
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: sorry is the first time i ask a question here, the problem is that this line :  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(166, 166, 3 * 166, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, intPtr1);
return a error : invalid parameter so i don´t know what is the problem exactly.

Comment: So you've got compilation problem? Please paste compiler error message.

Comment: when i debug the file it stop at this line :

Comment: when i debug the file it stop at this line :Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(166, 166, 3 * 166, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, intPtr1); pointing to fromat24bppRgb showing invalid parameter message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the pointer to the `cv::Mat` data is no longer valid after function `test()` returns, because variable `OriginalImg` gets out of scope, destructors have cleaned `OriginalImg` data. Try making `OriginalImg` global if it is possible to prevent automatic destroy of the variable.

In general, I recommend making a generic C++/CLI wrapper for OpenCV. A made [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147674/creating-an-c-cli-opencv-wrapper-to-use-in-c-sharp/22151311#22151311) about that. For example, I'm working now on the same problem as you and I'm creating a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object in C++/CLI without any `DllImport`s...

Comment: But if you have more issues, post it here.