# Wrap OpenCV C++ for use with C#

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, c++-cli

I am trying to wrap openCV for use with C#. This the first time I have tried wrapping C++.

I found this question and answer: [Creating an C++/CLI OpenCV wrapper to use in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147674/creating-an-c-cli-opencv-wrapper-to-use-in-c-sharp)

However I cannot get the solution to work. If, as told, I just copy the header files from my static library, I need to also link the openCV libs to c++/cli poject so the opencCV includes in the header files work.

However the project will not build due to MTd_StaticDebug does not match the MDd_DynamicDebug being used to build the c++/cli DLL.

Then I tried to abstract out the code, creating an entry class which itself did not reference any openCV types, this still will not build citing the MTd/MDd error.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Why don't you use EmguCV?

Comment: [opencvsharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) is also a good alternative and it has great support and constant [releases](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/releases)

Comment: I used opencvsharp in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out both EmguCV and OpenCvSharp. OpenCvSharp seemed to work the best for me.