# C# use of enum declared in C++ library

Tags: c#, c++, enums

I have a C++ library with an enum declaration, this library is used by a C# application. I want to use this enum on the C# side but it doesn't work. If I press F12 over ProfileType (go to definition) it opens a 'from metadata' file with:

```
namespace BatchProcessingLib
{
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    [NativeCppClass]
    public enum ProfileType
    {
    }
}
```

Which looks quite empty.

In the C++ header file its declared as:

```
public enum ProfileType
{
    ProfileTypeCross = 0,
    ProfileTypeDiag = 1,
    ProfileTypeUser = 2
};
```

I've tried just ProfileTypeCross or ProfileType.ProfileTypeCross but I always have a compiler error:

```
Error   CS0117  'ProfileType' does not contain a definition for 'ProfileTypeUser'
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: C++ uses C++ enums.  C# uses C# enums.  They are not entirely compatible, syntactically or semantically.

Comment: So this means you can't do it? And if not possible, what is the most elegant solution? For now I'm doing: "(ProfileType) 2" and the compiler is happy.

Comment: You may find this helpful... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765/importing-c-enumerations-into-c-sharp

Comment: From MS doc: In the original C and C++ enum types, the unqualified enumerators are visible throughout the scope in which the enum is declared. In scoped enums, the enumerator name must be qualified by the enum type name. C# needs scoped enums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did post a compromise solution for this, but apparently there is a better solution in C++11, using **enum classes**, a strongly typed and strongly scoped enum variant:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enum-classes-in-c-and-their-advantage-over-enum-datatype/

So the solution is, on the C++ side:

```
enum class ProfileType
{
    ProfileTypeCross = 0,
    ProfileTypeDiag = 1,
    ProfileTypeUser = 2
};
```

Didn't try it yet but it should work. Thank you Regis for pointing that out and the other stackoverflow thread also discussing this issue:

[Importing C++ enumerations into C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765/importing-c-enumerations-into-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this solution that works:

```
/// @remarks C++ enums are incompatible with C# so you need to go and check the corresponding C++ header file :-|
if (profileType == (ProfileType)0)
{
```

This way I don't have to re-declare the enum on the C# side and I keep a link to the original declaration, even though I can't use the text value names that are much more user friendly.

EDIT: Found a better solution, look for my other answer...

Answer (score 0):

C++ `enums` are 32 bits wide so you can declare the `enum` again in C# and use it from there.

On the C++ side

```
enum ProfileType
{
    ProfileTypeCross = 0,
    ProfileTypeDiag = 1,
    ProfileTypeUser = 2
};
```

On the C# side

```
enum ProfileType
{
    ProfileTypeCross = 0,
    ProfileTypeDiag = 1,
    ProfileTypeUser = 2
}
```

From here we can marshal the value straight to the `enum` type.

Comment: C# is already "seeing" the ProfileType enum, so I'll probably have a compiler error if I use the same enum name, right? I'm on holidays now but I'll try it later just to check.

Comment: Based on the error provided your C# app doesn't see the original enum so it shouldn't give you any errors.

Comment: It doesn't see any of the values ProfileTypeCross etc but it does see ProfileType. That's why the solution I proposed works.